# PHP DomDocument - Chinese characters inside script tag malformed

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to parse a simple HTML containing Chinese characters inside script tag. However, after processing by PHP DomDocument, those are converted to some weird characters.

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const str = "訂閱最新指南";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Trying different approaches to get correct output
echo $dom->saveHTMl();
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
echo utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));
echo utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML());
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const str = "&#35330;&#38321;&#26368;&#26032;&#25351;&#21335;";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const str = "&#35330;&#38321;&#26368;&#26032;&#25351;&#21335;";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html><html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const str = "&#35330;&#38321;&#26368;&#26032;&#25351;&#21335;";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const str = "&#35330;&#38321;&#26368;&#26032;&#25351;&#21335;";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to working without the `mb_convert_encoding`:

```php
<?php

$html = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const str = "訂閱最新指南";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

echo utf8_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));
```

result:

```html
<html>
<head><script>
            const str = "訂閱最新指南";
        </script></head>
<body>
    </body>
</html>
```

with `mb_convert_encoding`:

```php
<?php

$html = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const str = "訂閱最新指南";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);

echo html_entity_decode($dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement));
```

result:

```
<html><head><script>
            const str = "訂閱最新指南";
        </script></head><body>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: is there any other without removing `mb_convert_encoding`, as it's required to fix many other issues why parsing

Comment: Added an example with the convert encoding @GijoVarghese

Comment: `html_entity_decode` did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: I've a one more similar question if you're interested :) 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541631/gcsesearch-converted-to-search-when-using-php-domdocument

Comment: Unfortunately `html_entity_decode` also decodes string inside `code` tag which shouldn't be decoded. I've created a new post if you would like to check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598623/specify-utf-8-encoding-to-phps-domdocument-without-meta-tag

Comment: Did the solution provided for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541631/gcsesearch-converted-to-search-when-using-php-domdocument work?

Comment: I've commented it over there.