# Specify UTF-8 encoding to PHP's DOMDocument without meta tag

Tags: php, domdocument

I've the following HTML code that consists of a **Chinese word inside a `script` tag** and some **HTML code inside `code` tag**.

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            const str = "訂閱最新指南";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            <code>&lt;img src="cat.jpg"/></code>
        </pre>
        <p>The code for new line is <code>&lt;br/></code> in HTML.</p>
    </body>
</html>
EOD;
```

I'm parsing this code via PHP's `DOMDocument`. After `saveHTML()`, the chinese characters somehow converts to some weird characters. The only solution I found is to add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to the `<head>` tag.

Is there any other way to specify UTF-8 encoding without adding this meta tag?

Here is what all I've tried (none of them work):

```
// Default way. Chinese characters got encoded
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo $doc->saveHTML() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

// Passed UTF-8 as parameter. Chinese characters got encoded
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo $doc->saveHTML() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

// Set encoding. Chinese characters got encoded
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo $doc->saveHTML() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

// Using mb_convert_encoding. Chinese characters got encoded
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo $doc->saveHTML() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

// Use html_entity_decode to decode. But also enocdes string inside code tag
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($html);
echo html_entity_decode($doc->saveHTML()) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: You mention adding the meta tag works as expected. Can you tell us a bit more about which code you have control over and which not? Why is adding the meta tag not a good solution/why are you looking for another alternative?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to unconditionally override the encoding to UTF-8, you can do it by prepending the UTF-8 BOM to the file:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(str_starts_with($html, "\xEF\xBB\xBF")
    ? $html : ("\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $html));
```

The conditional expression is necessary because the library emits warnings if a double BOM is present at the beginning.

If you merely want to have UTF-8 as the default encoding instead of latin1, there is no clean way to do that. You can use the following dirty hack, though:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
if ($doc->encoding === null) {
    $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);
    $node = $doc->firstChild;
    while (!($node instanceof DOMProcessingInstruction)) {
        $node = $node->nextSibling;
    }
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

The above has the unfortunate side effect that when the encoding declaration is missing from the file, the parse time is effectively doubled. (Also note that the HTML specification [does not prescribe](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding) looking at `<?xml ?>` processing instructions to detect the character encoding, meaning this workaround relies on functionality contrary to the specification.)

To make sure characters are not mangled during serialisation back to markup, use `$doc->saveHTML($doc)` instead of `$doc->saveHTML()`. This will always result in UTF-8 text, even if the document contains a declaration specifying a different encoding. To obtain the document in another encoding, you will have to convert it afterwards, for example by doing `mb_convert_encoding($doc->saveHTML($doc), $doc->xmlEncoding, 'utf-8')` (which *should* convert to the original encoding, although even this may still contradict a `<meta>` element found in the actual DOM tree).

Given the number of workarounds necessary to use `DOMDocument` with anything approaching reliability, I’d strongly suggest switching to another parser. Preferably, to another programming language too.

Comment: To force the input encoding, you can prepend a UTF-8 BOM: `$doc->loadHTML("\xEF\xBB\xBF".$html);`.

Comment: @Olivier but it encodes Chinese characters to something else. Still not a solution to replace utf8 meta tag

Comment: @GijoVarghese It solves the **input** encoding issue. I didn't say it was solving the output encoding, which is a different problem.

Comment: @user3840170 I'm using this for a WordPress plugin. So using another language instead of PHP is not a solution

Answer (score -1):

I would simply add the meta as you've suggested, as i don't know what is blocking you with that, just know that this worked fine for me:

```
$meta='<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">';
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$doc->loadHTML($meta.$html); /* DOMDocument will put the meta at the right place */

echo $doc->saveHTML() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

or

```
echo str_replace($meta,'',$doc->saveHTML()) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```